# How to remove CakePHP's trailing timing benchmark comment

Tags: cakephp

I've been with this awful problem for hours, Googled as much as I can but still unlucky to figure out the solution.

The problem is:

each page rendered by CakdPHP has a default trailing timing benchmark comment, such as:

```
<html>
   <head />
   <body />
</html>
<!-- 3.4533s !-->
```

How can I remove the last line?enter code here?

Comment: 3.45 seconds?! Wow, you've got some optimization to do. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// core.php or anywhere else:
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Comment: Whoever just voted this up got me to 2500 rep. Please don't vote on my stuff for a little while, it's a nice number. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

you'll find the ouput in **webroot/index.php**

just remove:

```
echo "<!-- " . round(getMicrotime() - $TIME_START, 4) . "s -->";
```

at the end of the file.

Comment: It's useful to have for debugging purposes, you really shouldn't remove it completely. If you need to disable it because, for example, you're outputting XML, use The Intended Way™ to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Turn of debugging.

In AJAX heavy apps, I ensure I use the request handler component by putting it in the components list of any controller that will respond to AJAX requests.

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

I then put this the beforeFilter() method of the controller:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to manually echo out the render, and then quit the request.  Since the _stop() call will terminate your request, make sure you don't have to do anything after the rendering.

```php
function some_action() {
    echo($this->render());
    $this->_stop();
}
```