# How can i stop cakephp to stamp execution time of the page?

Tags: php, cakephp, time, echo, execution

> **Duplicate:**
>
> - [How to remove CakePHP's trailing timing benchmark comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220855/how-to-remove-cakephps-trailing-timing-benchmark-comment)

cakephp stamps execution time as html comment at the bottom of the page, something like

```
<!-- 4.031 s -->
```

How can i stop cakephp to output this??

I need to avoid this print because in some ajax queries (that fetch some data and display) i see it (example in an autocomplete where aren't so much results).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off debugging.

In AJAX heavy apps, I ensure I use the request handler component by putting it in the components list of any controller that will respond to AJAX requests.

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

I then put this the beforeFilter() method of the controller:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris has a good solution if you want to keep it around. If you want to permanently remove it, open up app/webroot/index.php and comment out the last 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to manually echo out the render, and then quit the request.  Since the _stop() call will terminate your request, make sure you don't have to do anything after the rendering.

```php
echo($this->render());
$this->_stop();
```